# How to add where clause condition of type varchar in dbms_xmlgen.getxml?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql

This is the query which I am trying

```
select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select * from CITY where CITY_NAME="ROME"') xml from dual
```

but it is giving error.

[image: image description here]

When I tried like  select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select * from CITY where CITY_ID=10446') xml from dual it worked fine.

Please can some one tell me how to add condition for varchar type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using pair of single quote for eg:

```
 select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select * from CITY where CITY_NAME=''ROME''  ') xml from dual
```

Comment: This is also not work.  ORA-00972: identifier is too long
00972. 00000 -  "identifier is too long"
*Cause:    An identifier with more than 30 characters was specified.
*Action:   Specify at most 30 characters.
Error at Line: 1 Column: 27